# Magento 2 - Add custom logic after Order creation

Tags: module, magento2, orders, api, sales-order

I've tried to push orders data to 3rdParty webservice. I created observer for event `sales_order_place_after` - order Id is missing there. I believe it's not a bug - order is not saved in database.

Next try.

I've tried `sales_order_save_after` - it gives empty array of items, no payment method information. Tried to reload it again with `ordermodel->load(id_of_order)` but it gives empty data again.
I'm pretty sure, order save event is raised before address, payment and other order stuff is saved in database or object in event is order prepared for save, so all additional informations are filtered out.

Any idea how to get correct order data on order place event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a list of events http://cyrillschumacher.com/magento2-list-of-all-dispatched-events/

I'm doing the same thing and ended up using 'checkout_onepage_controller_success_action'

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
    <observer name="mymodule_controller_success_action" instance="My\Module\Observer\MyObserver"  />
</event>
```

Comment: This would work for success payments such as Paypal payment for example? I see there are different events for Payal. Wha event would you use if you want to trigger an event after any success payment?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one `sales_model_service_quote_submit_success` from `Magento\Quote\Model::submitQuote` it's right after order is placed and before email send. You will get order ID also:

```
try {
            $order = $this->orderManagement->place($order);
            $quote->setIsActive(false);
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'sales_model_service_quote_submit_success',
                [
                    'order' => $order,
                    'quote' => $quote
                ]
            );
            $this->quoteRepository->save($quote);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'sales_model_service_quote_submit_failure',
                [
                    'order'     => $order,
                    'quote'     => $quote,
                    'exception' => $e
                ]
            );
            throw $e;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

"after" [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for `\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderManagementInterface::place` should help in this case.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to implement this? ;)

Comment: @Eduardo Check out here http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html how to create "after" plugins